# Host shared folder not working on ubuntu-23.10.1-desktop-amd64 guest

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders, 23.10

On *VirtualBox 7*, selected a folder on my Windows 10 host to share with Ubuntu 23.10.1:
[image]

But the content is not shown on Ubuntu (it's just loading - as shown in the screenshot below) and a green circle with number 1 is shown on the *Files* icon! The shared folder's data size is merely 1.42 MB.
[image]

Comment: Please reinstall the most recent Virtual Box Guest Additions software in the guest.

Comment: Updated it from 7.0.10 to 7.0.12 but still seeing the same issue (just loading and the green circle exists yet)!